# Ordered List does not inherit parent element class

Tags: html, css, inheritance

```
<p class="firstClass">
    I like exploring....
    I also invest my time in:
    <ol>
        <li>Movies</li>
        <li>Music</li>
        <li>Fitness</li>
    </ol> 
</p>
```

Why doesn't the `ol` element inherit the class of the `p` element, isn't it its parent?

Here is the CSS file

```
.firstClass{
    font-size: 23px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: What should inherit? We see nothing to check if this works or not.

Comment: You added the tag CSS. Where is it?

Comment: Classes are not inherited, only properties (color or font size for example).

Comment: .firstClass{
 font-size: 23px;
 font-family: sans-serif;
} It should have inherited the CSS i defined in the file

Comment: The `ol` is not in the `p`. A `p` can't contain `ol` elements, so the `ol` is put after it in the DOM tree, not in it. Check your code with the W3C validator.

Answer (score 4):

Make a `div` and put all inside it.

`p` cant contain `ol` elementes. `p` can contain `Phrasing content` and `ol` is `Flow content`. A div is needed here to contain all. [Documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element)

```css
.firstClass { 
font-size: 23px; 
font-family: sans-serif; 
}
```

```html
<div class="firstClass">
        I like exploring....
        I also invest my time in:
        <ol>
            <li>Movies</li>
            <li>Music</li>
            <li>Fitness</li>
        </ol> 
</div>
```

Comment: I know that if i wrap them in a div, all inside elements will inherit the properties of the DIV, but logically mine should have worked too.

Comment: @Shaw just answered that question. Thx Mr Lister btw.

Comment: @Yes, thanks, when i posted, then my page refreshed.Thanks for the answer!

Comment: You're welcome @Shaw . Just mark as correct if helpfull.

Comment: Nice answer. The documentation link is a big help for a learner!